# Team Drive vs Google Drive shared folders for team repository. Is Team Drive worth it at the moment?

Tags: google-workspace, google-drive-shared-drive

I am just trying to understand advantages of going to Team Drive for team repository on G suite vs using just shared folder on Google Drive. By searching different sources and doing testing I found the following results so far.

Frankly speaking this all makes me think whether Team Drive at the moment offers that much of advantage vs shared folder on Google Drive.

**Questions:**

1) did I miss anything in my analysis?

2) is there anything else Team Drive offers, which I did not mention?

3) Are there any other pitfalls (hidden problems) to use google Drive shared folders for team repository?

## Advantages of Team Drive vs shared folder on Google Drive:

**When contributors leaves the company, files they own will not disappear, if they were placed in Team Drive.**

This however can he resolved, by simple automation, that manager becomes an owner of the files of people, reporting to him, who left the company

**Edit access feature:**

In a Team Drive you can have editors / contributors, who do not get permissions to delete or move files. Well, this is a good feature and clear advantage.

## Limitations of Team Drive

**One gets the same permissions for all files in one Team Drive.**

Since most of the people contribute to some of the projects in one way or another, for us this means that everybody would get edit permissions for all project repositories in entire company, which is not what always desirable

**Not possible to manage access permissions in hierarchical way**

This is a consequence of the 1st one. In google drive say regional manager can have access permissions to entire region. He would then create subrigional folders and would assign them to sub-regional managers. Sub-regional managers would manager only their folders, but would not see other sub-regions folders. However permissions of regional manager would flow down and they will automatically see everything. Sub-regional managers would then create sub-folders for individual projects and give access permissions to individual Project Managers

In Team Drive such construction is not possible.

**File and / or folders cannot be in multiple locations**
This is really good feature of a Google Drive, which is missing in a Team Drive

**Amount of subfolder levels limitation**
It is [20 now](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7338880), but still, this is a limitation

**Amount of items (files/ folders) limitation**
This is [400 k now](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7338880), but still, this is a limitation

## Limitations with migration of files from Google Drive to Team Drive

**Links to folders will break.**
Links to the folders do not get preserved, when they get migrated to Team Drive

**Disappearing files / folders**

If there was a file or folder, which was in multiple locations and one of these locations was in the folder, migrated to Team Drive, than this Drive folder/file would disappear from other locations as well, not only from the folder, which was explicitly migrated to Team Drive.

Comment: Related (Web Applications): [When should I use a Google Team Drive over My Drive?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/123583/88163)

Answer (score 4):

I can add something to your analysis:

## Advantages of Team Drive

[Drive File Stream](https://www.google.com/drive/download/): it's a Dropbox-like app, it will mount a virtual disk on your system. Files copied/moved there don't take up disk space.

## Limitations of Team Drive

You can't share a folder, just singles files or the whole Team Drive. This is not something I would expect from an enterprise dedicated tool...

Comment: Thanks for input. 
the second limitation you described if the one I already mentioned:

_** One gets the same permissions for all files in one Team Drive**.

Since most of the people contribute to some of the projects in one way or another, for us this means that everybody would get edit permissions for all project repositories in entire company, which is not what always desirable_